# Detection of WebView load finish

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, swift2

I am creating a simple app with a WebView basing on [this tutorial](https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/4/16/web-view-with-loading-indicator-in-swift-xcode-63-os-x-1010-tutorial).

I would like to display a progress indicator while loading the page, but the methods `didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame` and `didFinishLoadForFrame` are never called. What am I doing wrong?

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewProgressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!
    let messengerUrl = "https://www.messenger.com/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: messengerUrl)!))
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func webView(sender: WebView!, didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!)
    {
        self.webViewProgressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
    }

    func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!)
    {
        self.webViewProgressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
    }
}
```

I am using Xcode 7 Beta and OS X 10.11 Beta.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial missed out something, Need to add:

```
self.webView.frameLoadDelegate = self
```

(can be done in connections inspector)

then call the load..

```
self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: messengerUrl)!))
```

Also add the WebFrameLoadDelegate interface to your ViewController.. (thanks tjv)

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, WebFrameLoadDelegate{  .....
```

Answer (score 2):

Rich's answer works on Xcode 7.0.1 ElCaptain Swift2

BUT I had to connect it in the connections inspector as Swift2 did not accept

`self.view.frameLoadDelegate = self`

as it gave the following error

> Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type
>   'WebFrameLoadDelegate!'

So as long as you connect it up as follows, all works great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the delegate of your `UIWebview` ie: `webview.delegate = self`

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Maybe it's not important, but I am not using `UIWebView`, but `WebView`.

Comment: did you make your `controller` conforms to `webView` delegate ?